# Vite proxy server does not rewrite POST requests

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, proxy, vite

After setting up a proxy using Vite, it only proxies GET and HEAD requests.

I need other methods to also be proxied.

on a fresh vite react project - only thing I touched was vite.config.ts

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    proxy: {
        '/test': {
            target: 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com',
            rewriteHost: true,
        }
    }
  }
})
```

`curl -X POST localhost:3000/test` causes the following log message when run with `vite --debug`

```
vite:html-fallback Not rewriting POST /test because the method is not GET or HEAD. +1ms
```

But instead I expected this to POST to https://google.com/test

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. The above config actually works. I found the error at the very top of the logs when starting the server. (in my case it was a bunch of DNS stuff I did not understand when proxying to Google - changeing to the example on vite's page worked)

I think as soon as you use a Regex - it only allows GET or HEAD. (unsure - but not using a regex fixed it for me)

Comment: I have the same problem and I really don't understand what you say in your solution. What regex? What DNS stuff? I don't see regex in your initially posted code? How was your vite.config.js before the solution and how was it after the solution? You don't help with such an answer.

Comment: @ThanasisIoannidis my question was terrible. The above config was not a proper reproduction of my problem - the error only occured when I used a Regex. Unfortunately it's been long enough I've forgotten the details of the issue. :(

Comment: Ok. In my case the error was that I did put the "proxy" entry in the root level of configuration and not under "server". When I put it under "server" everything worked just fine. Interestingly enough, vite was picking up the proxy configuration even from the root level (i could see that from the logs), but it didn't work as expected.